# Call c# method into the MainWindow

Tags: c#, methods, types, datatable

I have an easy thing to do for you, but I don't know why, I cannot.

This is my code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private BDDInterneEntities cnn = new BDDInterneEntities();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void SampleSolution(DataTable CapitalisationActuelle, DataTable DonneesDUMP)
    {
    var result = from table1 in CapitalisationActuelle.AsEnumerable();
                 join table2 in DonneesDUMP.AsEnumerable() on table1.Field<char>("PMRQTOTM") equals table2.Field<char>("PMRQTOTM")
                 where table1.Field<char>("PMRQTOTM") != table2.Field<char>("PMRQTOTM")
                 select table1;
    }
```

I want to execute this method: SampleSolution but I cannot call it into my MainPage,
If I do

```
SampleSolution = new SampleSolution();
```

I have the error: "WpfApplication3.MainWindow.SampleSolution(System.Data.DataTable, System.Data.DataTable) is a 'method' but is used like a 'type'

Somebody know what's wrong and what can I do to call my method on MainWindow?

Thanks in advance.
Florian SELVA

Edit 1:

```
private void SampleSolution()
{
    var result = from table1 in CapitalisationActuelle
                 join table2 in DonneesDUMP on table1.Field<char>("PMRQTOTM" equals table2.Field<char>("PMRQTOTM")
                 where table1.Field<char>("PMRQTOTM") != table2.Field<char>("PMRQTOTM")
                 select table1;
}
```

This is my current SampleSolution script.

Comment: you definitely don't want the semi-colon in your query

Comment: The code compiles I just made a grammatical mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is an instantiation of an object. You just want to call a method. A method call works just for itself. Like this:

```
SampleSolution();
```

Since the Tables CapitalisationActuelle and DonneesDUMP are available through EF you dont need to pass them to the method. Delete them from your methods declaration:

```
private void SampleSolution()
    {
    var result = from table1 in CapitalisationActuelle
                 join table2 in DonneesDUMP on table1.Field<char>("PMRQTOTM") equals table2.Field<char>("PMRQTOTM")
                 where table1.Field<char>("PMRQTOTM") != table2.Field<char>("PMRQTOTM")
                 select table1;
    }
```

Comment: But he cannot call it without arguments.

Comment: I Agree with @TimSchmelter, when I do this, I have "no overload for methos 'SampleSolution' takes 0 arguments)

Comment: @Kraenys: you first need an instance of `MainWindow` before you can use `SampleSolution` since it's not static. Then you need two DataTables for it. Isn't this your code?

Comment: Me 2. Where did you get that method from? I suggest, that you didn't implement it yourself.

Comment: When I do SampleSolution(CapitalisationActuelle, DonnéesDUMP);
I have: "The best Overloaded methos match for 'WPFApplication3.MainWindow.SampleSolution(System.Data.DataTable, System.Data.DataTable)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @RomanoZumbé No I haven't wrote it alone, I used something found on StackOverFlow. I try to find the answer to my question:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25481999/c-sharp-search-a-column-value-of-a-table-into-an-other-table)
But it's only some tries

Comment: @Kraenys: it would be interesting to know the types of `CapitalisationActuelle` and `DonnéesDUMP`.

Comment: This method works with two tables as input. In order to work you need those tables in the first place. Where do you create them?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I think I have answered to your question with my link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25481999/c-sharp-search-a-column-value-of-a-table-into-an-other-table)

Comment: @RomanoZumbé I have created them in a Database called BDDInterne.mdf, with EntityFramework, I have explained this at the other question, I can write it again as main post Edit if you want.

Comment: It helps, but now I only have the choice between CapitalisationActuelle.Equals or .ReferenceEquals, and it's the same for DonneesDUMP. AsEnumerable doesn't exist now, is that normal?
I'm not used to manipulate LinQ, I don't know what to choose. Moreover, now I can call SampleSolution from my MainWindow. I just have to understant why AsEnumerable disappeared and what write instead of.

Comment: Since you were using them as DataTables you needed to cast them to enumerables. If they are entites this is obsolete. Just use them without the method. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help @RomanoZumbé.
Now, CapitalisationActuelle has the error: "Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'WpfApplication3.CapitalisationActuelle'. 'Join' not found, even if join is just in the next line.

Furthermore, DonneesDUMP has the following error:
"WpfApplication3.DonneesDUMP is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'.

I edit my code to show you what I have